# Migrating DHCP from one server and subnet to another, one subnet fails to retrieve addresses

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

I just attempted to migrate the DHCP service from a 2008r2 server on vlan1 to a 2012r2 server on vlan20.   We had the dhcp helpers assigned on the core switch, firewall dhcp relays setup for the any vlans that required it.  After the move, the devices on vlan1 could not get an IP address, so same vlan as the old server.  All other vlans were able to retrieve addresses from the new server.

My migration process used powershell commands to backup DHCP including leases from the old server and imported them on the new server. Once the new server finished the import I deauthorized the server on vlan1 and authorized the new server on vlan20.  The old server remained on as it is still used for other Server Roles.

- When the devices on vlan1 failed to retrieve addresses, I also disabled DHCP Server in services.msc.
- I could ping the servers from either vlan.

My WAN person asked, "Did you shut off DHCP on the old one completely? It's on the VLAN and everything will look locally first b4 going through the Relay".  Shouldn't the deauthorize and or stopping the service be enough or would there be more to do?

Any ideas what went wrong?

--Edit/Update--
While the relays were setup correctly, and the migration process used was correct, if I recall correctly there was a Global Relay setting that was preventing the vlan 1 from finding the relay on the new vlan.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Have you enabled DHCP debug logging and examined the logs? Have you done a packet capture in VLAN 1 and 20 to confirm how far the DHCP packets are getting?

Comment: DHCP debug was enabled, still looking at the logs.
Attempted the packet capture but didn't narrow the scope to the machine I was on, so was flooded with info that didn't help.
I had to revert the move by deauthorizing the vlan20 server and authorizing the old vlan1, so pulling additional info right now is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Deauthorizing the DHCP server on VLAN1 should be enough to make it stop servicing DHCP clients. I would suggest a few things:

1. Delete any existing leases for the Scope for VLAN1 that were migrated to the new DHCP server on the new DHCP server. Those leases are no longer valid.
2. Verify that the VLAN1 Scope on the new server is correct.
3. Verify that your DHCP Relay is configured correctly after this change.
4. Run a simultaneous packet capture on the old DHCP server, the new DHCP server, and a VLAN1 DHCP client while running ipconfig/renew on the DHCP client. Then analyze all threee captures to see what's happening. You can filter the captures to show only DHCP traffic.

Comment: 1) vlan20 has been deauthorized and the old server reauthorized, but I will purge the leases before attempting this again.
2) Looks good
3) The screenshots I was provided appear that the DHCP Relay is correct.
4) what filter command should I use if I have wireshark to do the filtering, or is there a menu option?